# Regex в php: захват символа, находящегося НЕ в начале строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо заменить `a` на `b`, если `a` не является первым в строке символом.
Мне бы подошло это:

```
a(?!^)
```

Но так не работает, т.к. `^` не работает в скобках.

UPD: Ладно, давайте чуть иначе объясню: нужно не заменить `a` на `b`, а убрать `a`, если `a` - не первый символ.

Comment: например так `.+a`

Comment: Ваш вариант превратит "abba" в "bbbb". А должно быть "abbb"

Comment: а вы как пробовали?

Comment: Ваш вариант? preg_replace(/.+a/,'b','abba');
Вполне логично, что оно превращается все в bbb, т.к. мы захватываем и остальные символы

Comment: нужно просто группировку добавить, и то что вначале нашли - вставить тоже: `preg_replace('/(.+)a/','$1b','abba');` в строке возможно несколько `a`?

Comment: `a(?!^)` находит все `a`, после которых нет начала строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не правильно используете отрицательные [утверждения](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php) (negative-lookbehind). Нужно как-то так:

```
echo(preg_replace("/(?<!^)a/", '', 'abba')); // abb
```

Кстати, символ `^` очень даже хорошо работает в скобках. Просто нужно знать, как именно его применять ;)

https://regex101.com/r/nU9fL9/2

**UPD:**

Альтернативный вариант без использования якоря начала строки:

```
echo(preg_replace("/(.)a+/", '$1', 'abaaaaba')); // abb
```

Comment: (Просто regex - невероятно запутанная жуткая фиговина, которая, к великому сожалению, бывает нужна. Понять же ее я не могу, хотя стараюсь и мануалы читаю). Спасибо

Comment: Кстати, `"/(?!^)a/"` тоже работает отлично.